# Extraction of specific words from .json document

Tags: python, api, extract

I'm writing here because I'm currently stuck in my research on malware analysis and haven't found anything about my problem either on the internet or here in the forum. In a nutshell, I would like to classify malware using various machine learning classifiers. The classification is to be based on N-Grams of the API call sequence. Having been able to run the malware in a first step, I now have log files consisting of thousands of such blocks:

```
"category": "file",  
"status": 1,  
"stacktrace": [],  
"api": "NtCreateFile",  
"return_value": 0,  
"arguments": {. 
"create_disposition": 1,  
"file_handle": "0x000080",  
"filepath": "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\vbc.exe",  
"desired_access": "0x80100080",  
"file_attributes": 0,  
"filepath_r": "\?? 
 \C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\vbc.exe",
"create_options": 100,  
"status_info": 1,   
"share_access": 1.
```

The aim now is to have only the API calls for each malware file in a document and not all the other information such as status, arguments, etc. I think that a possible procedure would be to iterate over the log files using a loop and only keep the lines that contain "api:". However, only the API calls themselves should be kept (not the whole line), so in this block it would be: NtCreateFile. Another possibility I could imagine regarding the implementation would be to have a dictionary with all API calls and then apply this to the log files in such a way that only words contained in the dictionary are kept.
I hope my problem is understandable and you can help me with the implementation using Python (unfortunately I'm not that experienced yet) or give me a tip or two.
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: That looks like json. I would parse it with the `json` module.

Comment: Yeah its a json. Can you explain me how to parse it with the json module?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/json.html?highlight=json

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) has many recipes for handling JSON with the `json` module.

Comment: That was helpful, thank you very much. Now I can read out the values. However, only at one point.  
Example:   print(data["signatures"][3]["marks"][0]["call"]["api"])
  
Question now is how I can read out not one value but all of them. So I want all the values that the key "api" contains in the whole json. This is not easy for me, because the api calls are located at different "depths" of the nesting and there are far too many to always find the exact index. Is there a way to globally read out all the entries for the "api" key in the json at once?